# Python script to transfer certain files after intervals

Tags: python

I have a python code which transfers files from folder a to folder b
In that folder if there are many files (30 for example) I need to transfer only 5 files at a time,
Following is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, time

src_path = "/opt/tst1/"
dst_path = "/opt/tst1/consume/"

now = time.time()
cutoff = now - (5 * 60)

count = 5
files = os.listdir(src_path)

for f in files:
        fn = src_path + f
        if not os.path.isfile(fn):
            continue
    t = os.stat(fn)
    c = t.st_ctime

    if c > cutoff:
            continue

    # move the file
    dfn = dst_path + f
    os.rename(fn, dfn)
count -=1
if count == 0:
    Break
```

It copies the entire contents of the folder from 1 folder to another, as opposed to copy only 5 files at the time, is there anything that needs to be added

Comment: ok so what about the code?

Comment: It copies all contents of the folder as opposed to 5 at a time, is there anything that needs to be added in the code I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

this code will send 5 files at a time until all files are exausted

```
files = os.listdir(".")
while files:
    print "COPY 5"
    for i in range(5):
        try:
           next_file = files.pop() #get the next file if we can
        except IndexError:
           print "DONE!"  #if we cant we are done
           break
        print next_file
        do_something(next_file)
    print "Resting"
    time.sleep(however_long)
```